# Changing the output order of Nodewords meta tags in head

Tags: 6, meta-tags

I have a request to change the order that meta items are printed in the head using the contrib module Nodewords in D6.  More specifically the property would like the description to appear before the keywords (per their SEO consultant).

Is this possible?  Fruitless?  Stupid?

I have searched with no results so far.

Comment: Which version of nodewords are you using ?

Comment: Nodewords version 6.x-1.11 -- I can upgrade if necessary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement [hook_nodewords_tags_alter](http://drupalcode.org/project/nodewords.git/blob_plain/refs/heads/6.x-1.x:/API.txt) which will alter the rendering of the tags. It accepts `function MODULENAME_nodewords_tags_alter(&$output_tags, $tag_options) {}`.

But why do you want to do this ? Any SEO insight you might share with us ?

Comment: sorry for the delay.  according to our SEO consultant, Google recommends meta tags display in the head in this order title>>description>>keywords -- I am not an SEO wizard so this insight is news to me.

Comment: @jeff good to know, maybe this could lead to some improvement of the nodewords module ;)

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to add hook_nodewords_tags_info_alter() to the next release of 1.x: http://drupal.org/node/1730808

Damien McKenna
Nodewords maintainer

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the branch 6.x-2, you need to implement `hook_nodewords_tags_info_alter()` to alter the weight index contained in the array returned by the implementations of `hook_nodewords_tags_info()`.

The weight is used by `_nodewords_output_tags()`, which is the function that renders the HTML output for the meta tags. Once the function has built the array of HTML strings to output, it sorts the array using the following code:

```
if (count($output)) {
  array_multisort($weights, $output);

  return implode("\n", $output);
}
else {
  return '';
}
```

`$weights` is the array containing the weight of every output meta tag.

I don't see any reason to change the weight of a meta tag, if not in a specific case where a meta tag consumer looks for two meta tags, and uses the first one that finds. Without a specific and valid reason, changing the weight of meta tags is useless, as meta tag consumers don't normally depend from the order meta tags are present in the HTML output.

`_nodewords_output_tags()` is called after the implementations of `hook_nodewords_tags_alter()`; altering the order of the array items in `hook_nodewords_tags_alter()` doesn't then have any effect.

```
nodewords_load_all_includes('nodewords.hooks.inc');
drupal_alter('nodewords_tags', $output_tags, $options);
$output = _nodewords_output_tags($output_tags);
drupal_alter('nodewords_tags_output', $output, $options);
```

Comment: What I reported in my answer is probably true for the 6.x-1 branch too; I didn't look at the code, and I cannot report any difference between the branches too.

Comment: Nope doesn't exists in the 6.x-1 branch...